# What does probe number and segmentation mean in copy number variation (CNV) data

Tags: genetics, tcga, copy-number-variation

In TCGA Copy number variation (CNV) data there is a column with title Num_Probes. What is the meaning of probe number with respect to the sample data below?

```
Chromosome  Start   End Num_Probes  Segment_Mean
1   61735   62152   4   1.1973
1   62920   12777697    6514    2.2882
```

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybridization_probe), probes are usually 100-1000 bases long. Then does it mean in the first row above that, it took 4 probes to identify the region(61735 - 62152). In that case what would be the meaning of Segment_Mean?

Answer (score 3):

The data you posted looks like it was produced by [GISTIC](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=18077431), a [program commonly used by TCGA](http://www.cbioportal.org/faq.jsp) to detect copy number changes. Assuming the data really is GISTIC-produced, my understanding is that "Segment_Mean" refers to the [average Log2 Ratio](https://www.biostars.org/p/133927/) of the probes in that particular segment. Looks like the copy-number of your 4-probe segment in your example is slightly less than half the copy-number of the longer segment.

You can also try using the [GISTIC Google-Group](https://groups.google.com/a/broadinstitute.org/forum/#!forum/gistic-forum) to learn more.

Comment: If a a sample has a CNV gain at 12792599 - 13278863 with probe no 100 and segmentation mean 0.4 and if another sample also has a CNV gain at the same position 12792599 - 13278863 with probe no 200 and segmentation mean 0.5, does this mean 2nd CNV region is more important than 1st CNV region? I don't understand the importance of segmentation here.

Comment: Simplistic Answer: higher segment mean == higher copy number. The number for probes for each region probably doesn't matter. Also, a difference of 0.1 between each regions' segment mean probably doesn't matter much either.